# How can I get FCKEditor in Drupal to stop re-escaping my HTML?

Tags: html, drupal, fckeditor, html-entities

I am creating a block and using the FCKEditor rich text input box. I switch to Source mode and enter in the following HTML:

```
<img src="http://test.com/image.png" alt="an image" />
```

I check to confirm that input format is set to "Full HTML" and press Save.  Upon loading my site, I discover that the HTML in FCKEditor's Source view is now:

```
<p><img alt="\&quot;an image" src="\&quot;http://test.com/image.png\&quot;" /></p>
```

Obviously that prevents the image from rendering properly since the browser sees the path to the image as:

```
"http://test.com/image.png"
```

Does someone know how to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick workaround could be to not use the quotes since it seems to be adding them in anyway.
Example:

```
<img src=http://site.com/image alt=alt text>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed or selected a suitable text format?

If you go to `admin/config/content/formats`, you can update or even create a new text format.

Select the one you're currently using that is resulting in this problem, and check if one of the filters is creating this problem. There are some that can influence or generate the problem you're experiencing.

- "*Correct faulty and chopped off HTML*" filter
- "*Convert URLs into link*" filter
- "*Limit allowed HTML tags*" filter

Also, check in the FCKEditor's config page if any auto-correction filter is activated.

In any case, if the problem is inserting images, I think you should be better off with a dedicated module, like **IMCE** (http://drupal.org/project/imce).

Hope it helps.